# Excel last appearance of a given string in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am using the     LOOKUP function to find the last appearance of a given string in a provided column, like this:

```
LOOKUP(A3;Runs!D3:D6;Runs!A3:A6)
```

However, the bounds in the vector are hard-coded: Runs!A3:**A6**. I want this value to be dynamically set to the last cell with data of the column. I found this formula that gives the last row index:

```
COUNTA(Runs!A:A)
```

This other function gives me the cell reference (the content of the cell), but I can't seem to merge it with the LOOKUP formula:

```
INDIRECT("Runs!A"&COUNTA(Runs!A:A))
```

Is there any way to set the upper bound for LOOKUP dinamically?

EDIT: there are no blank rows in the row range.

Regards

Comment: COUNTA doesn't necessarily give you the last row of the range.  That works only if the data starts in row 1 and there are no blank entries.  Is COUNTA is giving you the right answer, the lower bound is 1.

Comment: Edited the answer: I meant the UPPER bound, not the lower. Data is contiguos in the column (there are no blank rows in the range)

Comment: I assumed that's what you meant.  COUNTA counts entries and ignores blanks.  Say COUNTA results in 10.  If the last row of the range actually is 10, that means that the range started in row 1.  If the range started in, say, row 3, the end of the range would have to be row 13 for COUNTA to be 10, so the end point would be incorrect in your formula.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is it that you want to find the last occurrence of the string or that you want to dynamically set the lookup range? Because your lookup isn't doing that.

Comment: @fixer1234 the lower bound is fixed, so that won't be the problem

Comment: @Raystafarian I want to set the upper bound for the vector passed as argument for LOOKUP

Comment: I still don't get it. You want to use `lookup(value,range(dynamic:set),range(dynamic:set)` to find the last occurrence of the lookup value?

Comment: To find the actual last occurrence you can just use `lookup(2,1/((range)="value"),return range)` so `lookup(2,1/runs!D:D=A3,runs!A:A)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this. Thank you all for your comments, the answer from fixer1234 was specially useful. The LOOKUP wasn't giving accurate results, so I changed it for a INDEX/MATCH pair. Also added a N/A check.

```
IF(ISNA(INDEX(INDIRECT("Runs!A3:A"&COUNTA(Runs!A:A)), MATCH(A3, INDIRECT("Runs!D3:D"&COUNTA(Runs!D:D)), 0))), "", INDEX(INDIRECT("Runs!A3:A"&COUNTA(Runs!A:A)), MATCH(A3, INDIRECT("Runs!D3:D"&COUNTA(Runs!D:D)), 0)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I get it--the problem is getting your dynamic range to work as a range specification within LOOKUP.  You were almost there.  Try this:

```
    LOOKUP(A3;INDIRECT("Runs!D3:D"&COUNTA(Runs!D:D));Runs!A3:A6)
```

Answer (score 1):

the offset() function will solve your issue

replace Runs!A3:A6 with **OFFSET($A$3,0,0,COUNTA($A$3:$A$1000),1)**

you can get a bit fancy with a Dynamic Define Range http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830287